# Equation doesn't add up? PHP

Tags: php, equation

I'm stuck!

When I run the code it echos 82374928408977024.
But I know for a fact (or at least im pretty sure) that 15323523 *2 + 82374928378329992 equals to 82374928408977038.
Too large strings? In addition, I would like to echo the result in a plain number format without scientific notations.

```
<?php
$number = "15323523";
$result = $number * 2 + 82374928378329992;
echo sprintf('%f', $result);
?>
```

Thanks a bunch to anyone who can help me with this.

Comment: Just read the manual: http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.float.php There is some text in a red box

Comment: If you don't want scientific notation, then why are your formatting your number as a float? It works perfectly fine without it: http://codepad.viper-7.com/4x8qXC

Comment: If you're doing math with very large numbers (and don't want to lose any precision) use [bcmath](http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) or [gmp](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php)

Comment: This is what I get Jeroen: 8.2374928408977E+16 unless I use echo sprintf('%f', $result);

Answer (score 0):

`82374928408977038` requires 56 bits to represent because it can be be divided by 2.

`82374928408977024` can be represented as 2^7 * 643554128195133, which only requires 50 bits, which fits the 52 bits of the Significand, and being the closest number that can be represented.

As a side note, `82374928378329992` does not fit either.